# Regex for HTTP URL with Basic authentication

Tags: c#, regex, url

In my application, I must read a URL and do something if the URL contains Basic authentication credentials. An example of such a URL is

http://username:password@example.com

Is the regular expression below a good fit for my task? I am to capture four groups into local variables. The URL is passed to another internal library that will do further work to ensure the URL is valid before opening a connection.

```
^(.+?//)(.+?):(.+?)@(.+)$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks ok, and I think that a regular expression is good to use in this case. A couple of suggestions:

1) I think that named groups would make your code more readable, i.e:

```
^(?<protocol>.+?//)(?<username>.+?):(?<password>.+?)@(?<address>.+)$
```

Then you can simply write

```
Match match = Regex.Match(string, pattern);
if (match.Success) {
    string user = match.Groups["username"];
```

2) then you could make the expression a little more strict, e.g. using `\w` when possible instead of `.`:

```
^(?<protocol>\w+://)...
```

Comment: One problem with trying to apply this more broadly: basic auth does not require both a username and a password. Example:

`http://user@domain.com`

Answer (score 5):

Your regex seems OK, but why not use the thoroughly-tested and nearly-compliant [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)? It's then trivial to access the pieces you want without worrying about spec-compatibility:

```
var url = new Uri("http://username:password@example.com");
var userInfo = url.UserInfo.Split(':');
var username = userInfo[0];
var password = userInfo[1];
```

Comment: @Mike: Are you sure Uri can't handle it? It [works fine in Mono](http://ideone.com/TrClc).